# Vimeo authorization is not working, redirect_uri didn't match?

Tags: oauth, vimeo, vimeo-api

I write the code to redirect the user to Vimeo for authorization.

```
https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={myownurl}test&state=INDIA
```

When this url opened in browser It say "Dear app owner, your redirect URL appears to be misconfigured. Check your application settings and make sure it matches the redirect_uri parameter of your authorization code request."

I remove the client_id and redirect_url for privacy reason. Can someone check what is wrong in this URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the `redirect_uri` you have mentioned in the IdP when you were registering the client application is different from the one you have included in the above request.